# How to provide standard library sources for IntelliJ IDEA's Rust project?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, homebrew

I am using Mac for development. I installed Rust 1.13.0 using `brew install rust` and the Rust plugin 0.1.0.1385 for IntelliJ IDEA. I created my first test project with `cargo` and while opening it with IDEA I got the message

> No standard library sources found, some code insight will not work

I haven't found any sources installed, nor the Rust sources package in Homebrew.

How do I provide sources for the project and what are the practical implication if I ignore this step?

Comment: I would recommend using `rustup`, it downloads the correct sources, updates them together with the compiler tools and allows version switching. https://rustup.rs/ Without sources, IDEA will not know about any `std` types or values, which basically makes code completion completely useless.

Comment: I had the same question on in linux because I used `asdf-vm` to install rust - https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-rust/issues/18

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As commented, the supported approach is to use `rustup`:

- Navigate to https://rustup.rs/ and follow the installation instructions for your platform.
- Add the `rust-src` component by running: `rustup component add rust-src`
- Create a new Rust project in IntelliJ and choose your existing Rust project source.  If the folder already contains previous IntelliJ project files, you may have to delete those first before it will let you proceed.
- IntelliJ-Rust should automatically configure the standard library sources to point to the sources downloaded by `rustup`.

Comment: There appears to be a download button right in the IDE now: https://i.imgur.com/p0Q7PZZ.png

Comment: @mpen: unfortunately, this link is not available any more in IDEA 20.1.3.

Answer (score 15):

As a reference, since the question title is broad, for **Fedora 28** I had to:

```
dnf install cargo rust-src
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/rustlib/src /usr/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/
```

then give `/usr/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/src/rust/src` as "Standard library"

Full setup:
[image]

[Issue](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/2395) opened to simplify the process

Comment: who do you need to use a symlink here? it works fine for me without the symlink by just selecting `/usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src` in intellij

Comment: @msrd0 see the *Issue* link. It is (was?) a bug.

Answer (score 6):

When not using the rustup installer, one can install the source package and direct the rust plugin to use those:

[image]

(Tested with CLion 2020.2.1, rust-1.46.0-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.msi, rustc-1.46.0-src.tar.gz. Offline Rust installers and source archive from there: https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html )

Answer (score 5):

Although the preferred way of installing Rust is by using rustup, as pointed out by the other posts, it is not uncommon to use the packages that your distro makes available.

I use, for example, the packages provided by Gentoo and I share the same problem about the not prefilled field for standard libraries.
Nevertheless, you can easily find out where your standard libraries have been installed by typing the following find command:

```sh
find /usr/lib* -type d -name "rust" | grep src
```

or the following if you installed rust in your home

```sh
find  -type d -name "rust" | grep src
```

The previous commands will help, unless, of course, in your distro there is a package for the binaries and one for the source and you only installed the binary one.

Comment: I'm also using Gentoo. Having installed:

[I] dev-lang/rust 1.32 (-clippy -debug -doc -libressl -rls -rustfmt -system-llvm -wasm)

I cannot seem to find the standard libraries anywhere... Any ideas why they are missing here?

Comment: @opncow, I had the same trouble, found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60576683/2598608 - Use the "rls" useflag for rust to have sources installed.

Comment: Thanks you @ScottTiger! Completely missed this useflag.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is for MacOS but this answer is shown up when searching for it on Linux. Below I will answer for Ubuntu.

The path is `/usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src` for Ubuntu 20.04

---

The way I did is:

- Installed rustc from the repositories, which includes cargo

```
sudo apt install rustc
```

- Then installed rust source package

```
sudo apt install rust-src
```

- I used `apt-file` (can be installed with `sudo apt install apt-file`) to search for the install path of the sources

```
sudo apt-file update
apt-file list rust-src
```

This show the path as `/usr/src/rustc-1.41.0/src` .

But a `ls -la` in `/usr/lib/rustlib/` will reveal symlinks and `/usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src` points to the previous found directory.

Using the symlink on IntelliJ will survive new rust versions.

Comment: Thanks mate. been fussing with this all day. ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `/usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src` worked for me on Debian 11.

Answer (score 4):

For Fedora 32 install Rust using command:

```
dnf install cargo rust-src
```

and the path to standard libary source is:

```
/usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust
```

Answer (score 3):

I used Ubuntu. I follow these steps:

1. `sudo apt install rust-src`
   wait for the install, then
2. `dpkg -L rust-src`
   copy the last line. For me it is the standard library path:

> /usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS, you need to put `/opt/homebrew/bin/`.